# Is it possible to add MVN option in CLI?

Tags: maven

Is it possible to add to run mvn as command with profile or Repository or other element and not from settings.xml ?

for example

```
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <localRepository>/home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/temp/maven_repo_6194547201292702175</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode>false</interactiveMode>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>public.nexus</id>
          <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
           </repository>
        </profile>
      </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>public.nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: In case of repositories it is not possible. With profiles you can do `mvn -PprofileName`....

Comment: what is the use case only for profiles ? do we need to define the profile before ?

Comment: @user1365697 Could you explain in more detail what you want to achieve? Then it may be easier to find a maven-like solution. Why do you want to use Maven without settings.xml? You know that you can provide a custom settings.xml on the command line?

Comment: I don't want to use settings.xml file but to do it with command line , the reason is problem of security in my case. is it possible to tell to mvn to use those repo and to active a profile from command line ?

Comment: As I already mentioned. To define a repository in that way is not possible without `settings.xml` I don't understand your reason related to security...furthermore using a profile on command is possible as I mentioned if you remove the `<activeProfiles>..</activeProfiles>` entry from your settings.xml... But I recommand to use a repository manager and simply configure the different repositories in your repository manager...